# read line by line and character by character c#

Tags: c#, newline, streamreader

So I'm getting a little overwhelmed with all of c#'s streamreader methods.  Is it possible for me to be able to read just the first letter of a line and then if the line starts with a character I specify, then read all the letters individually?  The part I'm having a hard time with is how do it get it to skip a line when it reads the first character of that line.  Like would a loop till the next cr/lf work if I read it character by character?  I can't use readline() because some lines I'll need to read character by character and readline() stops at a lf and I need it to ONLY go to the next line during cr/lf pairs only.

Comment: Hi Saif, can you please show us some code of what you have tried?

Comment: Why not simply read the text line by line into a string variable, while checking the first character in that string. If the character you want is found, do something with the string in that variable, otherwise, disregard it and move on?

Comment: I have tried writing it in just pseudocode but I guess I'm getting stuck at the beginning so I don't get far.  I COULD read every line (can't use readline() because that goes to the next line when it hits a 'LF' and I need it to include single 'LF' as part of the line and ONLY move to the next line when it hits a 'CR/LF' pair.  I guess I am just trying too hard to make this program fast and efficient but I think that's out of my league right now.  I think I will read EVERY character from 'CR/LF' and if the first value of that string array is one of the ones I don't want, then it'll do nothing

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should do the trick.

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();

using (var file = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    string line = string.empty;
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line[0] == chr)
        {
            lines.Add(line);
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(lines.Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, but, I guess you want something like this (*skipping the lines that starts with some special char and processing the rest*)

```
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(filename).Where(line=> !line.StartsWith("#")))
{
    //Process(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the the [StreamReader.Read method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ath1fht8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

keep a reference to the previously read character in a variable in order to identify if you've found a CR/LF pair.